# como obtener la ruta del archivo subido a firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase

resulta que estoy intentando obtener la url del archivo que se sube exitosa mente a firebase pero no he podido obtenerlo no se que anda mal, agradezco cualquier ayuda.
este es el código que sube el archivo correctamente

```
function subirArchivo(archivo) {

  // creo una referencia al lugar donde guardaremos el archivo
  var refStorage = storageService.ref('img').child(archivo.name);
 
  // Comienzo la tarea de upload
  var uploadTask = refStorage.put(archivo);

  // defino un evento para saber qué pasa con ese upload iniciado
  uploadTask.on('state_changed', null,
    function(error){
      alert('Error al subir el archivo');
    },
    function(){
//aqui es donde quiero ver la url  de la imagen subida
      alert('Subida completada');
      mensajeFinalizado(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL, uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes);
 
        var img = document.getElementById('im');
        img.src = storageRef.child(refStorage).getDownloadURL();
     

    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta de esta manera, Yo he usado Angular, y agregué use el *async - await* para poder obtener la respuesta, hice esto y me funcionó, `getDownloadURL()` retorna una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
async function(){
....
img.src = await storageRef.child(refStorage).getDownloadURL().then(url=> url);
```